# Error 400: invalid_request Missing required parameter: redirect_uri c#

Tags: c#

I keep getting this error when trying to create a webapp on the .Net framework using a localhost. This is my first ever project and i've hit a wall here, any fixes?

```
        request.AddQueryParameter("client_id", credentials["web"]["client_id"].ToString());
        request.AddQueryParameter("client_secret", credentials["web"]["client_secret"].ToString());
        request.AddQueryParameter("code", code);
        request.AddQueryParameter("grant type", "authorization code");
        request.AddQueryParameter("redirect_uri", "http://localhost/oauth2/callback");
```

Comment: Maybe you could look error message [OAuth HTTP error response reference](https://docs.apigee.com/api-platform/reference/policies/oauth-http-status-code-reference) and find out your problems

Comment: I suggest you use a tool like Fiddler to see if that parameter is being passed. That will tell you if the problem is the client or the server.

Comment: I am not sure this may be the reason but I suggest to change to `grant_type` and `authorization_code`..